# Mariadb syntax error in multipleStatements

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench, mariasql

When i am trying to execute the multipleStatements in Mariadb like this

```
db.Connection.query("CALL tep_procedure_out(?,@out_value);Select @out_value",["rahul"],
```

I set  {multipleStatements: true} in  my connection even though i am getting Error.

{ Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select @out_value' at line 1 code: 1064 }

Comment: Are you using node.js ?

Comment: Don't combine multiple statements.

Comment: yes, I am using Nodejs v8.7.0@RaymondNijland

Comment: I had requirement of doing both insert and select queries in Single Statement - @RickJames

Comment: Then have the Procedure end with the desired `SELECT(s)`.

Comment: ya, i did that.But my Question is MariaDB supports multipleStatements or not?@RickJames

Answer (score 1):

By default sending multiple statements is disabled (not only in node.js but in most other connectors) for security reasons.

If you want to use multiple statements you have to specify it when establishing the connection:

```
var conn = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

Comment: Thanks  for the Reply @Georg Richter, but i have Already set  multipleStatements: true in my connection and one more correction This about Mariadb not Mysql